# Как сделать так, чтобы по второму нажатию на кнопку окно tkinter возвращало свои размеры

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, gui, button

Как можно сделать так, чтобы, при повторном нажатии на кнопку в окне tkinter, размеры окна менялись на исходные?

код:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk



root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("300x300+50+50")
root.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
root.overrideredirect(1)
def clop():
    root.geometry("70x28")
b = tk.Button(root, text='close/open', command= lambda: clop())
b.place(x=0, y=0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk


class Demo:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.flag = True
        self.root = root
        b = Button(root, text='close/open', command=lambda: self.clop(self.flag))
        b.place(x=0, y=0)

    def clop(self, flag):
        if self.flag:
            self.root.geometry("70x28")
        else:
            self.root.geometry("300x300+50+50")
        self.flag = not self.flag 
        

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("300x300+50+50")
root.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
root.overrideredirect(1)

app = Demo(root)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]